# Scraping code not working in php to form controls

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape webpage content to my form controls, Without function i am getting output, but when i created function and assigned to button click event to display the output in textbox its not working, let me know where i am messed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Assign()
{
$html = file_get_contents("http://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=79401:006:0812");
preg_match_all('(<li.*?>.*?</li>)', $html, $matches);
$one=$matches[0][0];
document.getElementById("OutputField").value = $one;
}
</script>
<input id="OutputField" type="text" style="width:200px"/>
<input type="button" value="Assign Value" onclick="Assign()"/>
```

Comment: wow a literal mixture

Comment: You're mixing JavaScript and PHP - you cannot directly run PHP in a JavaScript function, you have to use AJAX to run a PHP file if you want to mix the two.

Comment: OMG, using any other method this same code will work.?

Comment: I am surprised, why its "-1", we are here to learn, we know lot genius here, but give a chance to learn new things.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I am surprised it is not -10 by now. As @JayBlanchard said, you need to use Ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you must separate your html, php, javascript code.
I changed your code and you can try it.
If you use it in right way it will work.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=79401:006:0812");
preg_match_all('(<li.*?>.*?</li>)', $html, $matches);
$one=$matches[0][0];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Assign() {
        document.getElementById("OutputField").value = "<?=$one?>";
    }
</script>

<input id="OutputField" type="text" style="width:200px"/>
<input type="button" value="Assign Value" onclick="Assign()"/>
```

I hope it was helpful for you.
You must study and study. ;-)

Comment: If possible, can we pass value, once button clicked from another textbox, to php, $html = file_get_contents("http://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=79401:006:0812"); For this link "79401:006:0812" can we enter in textbox?

Comment: Yes you can but you need to read information that @smoes advises you. Because you must to understand about "execution paradigms". I used your code for showing to you how it is work. But it is bad practice to mix html, javascript and php code in one file.
Your next issue can be resolved in different ways: You can use form submitting or ajax as you can see in earlier comments for your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two different execution paradigms here:

**PHP is executed server-side.** That means that the server, hosting your code executes it. As a consequence PHP code is usually not visible to clients. The execution of the php code is triggered by a clients request, and the output of the script (e.g. produced by the printf-function) is passed to the client.

**Javascript however, is executed client-side.** This implies that the cpu of the website visitor is actually used to execute the code. The code is 100% visible to the client. So what you paste within an HTML documents script-tags is executed client side. It is seen by the client. Contrary, PHP code is not meant to be directly pasted within script tags.

These are very generalized statements, that do always hold. However, they should give you a rough sketch. There is a quite nice answer in [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) that should help you for a better distinction. **You should certainly learn these basics, before continuing.**