# Pass value to php variable

Tags: javascript, php

This post is the continuation of my previous post, i missed one point, so i started new thread. I got solution for my previous post and my final code looks like below:

[Scrapping code not working in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016703/scrapping-code-not-working-in-php/26017527#26017527)

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("http://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=79401:006:0812");
preg_match_all('(<li.*?>.*?</li>)', $html, $matches);
$one=$matches[0][0];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Assign() {
    document.getElementById("OutputField").value = "<?=$one?>";
}
</script>

<input id="OutputField" type="text" style="width:200px"/>
<input type="button" value="Assign Value" onclick="Assign()"/>
```

On further i have added one more input box at the end, In that textbox, i am going to input my values in runtime, so once i clicked my button, textbox value will go to php variable and then that variable will assign after "ky=". I tried few things like POST and GET method, Again i missed something.

I am looking some thing like

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://geoportaal.maaamet.ee/url/xgis-ky.php?ky=" + $PHPvariable);
```

Comment: You don't need PHP for any of this. You could use javascript to extract the variable from the original url and set the value in the text box, when you change it just make a request to the url with your new value. Adding PHP into the mix is complicating this.

Comment: Disregarding the unnecessary php for a sec, beware of your preg_match_all, that could get greedy and return things you don't want.  Try `preg_match_all('{<li[^>]*>(?:[^<]+|<(?!/li))*</li>}', $html, $matches)`. it is a lot more literal than your expression and shouldnt run into any greed issues

Comment: You need to learn basic PHP. `+` is mathematical addition. `string + string` will give you something totally unexpected. Try `.` instead, which is the concatenation operator

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about handling forms and form information in PHP:

http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php